# Узнать права процесса в Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd

Вот у меня есть запущенный процесс, я знаю его имя и id, могу ли я как-то посмотреть, есть ли у него права на создание и удаление файлов? Я не смог в гугле ничего найти, поэтому спрашиваю тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно в каком каталоге хотите проверить права (предположим в произвольном).
Решение разбивается на 3 задачи:

1. Найти владельца процесса. Например так:

@set pid=6880
@for /f "delims=, tokens=7,8*" %%i in ('@tasklist /fi "pid eq %pid%" /v /fo csv /nh') do @echo.%%i

2. Определить в какие группы он входит

2.1 Если можно выполнить задачу от его имени, то можно создав список:

```
whoami /group
```

2.2 Определить список локальных групп:

```
wmic path win32_Group where (LocalAccount = "True") get Name,SID
```

2.3 Проверить совпадение списков.

3. Проверить права.

3.1 Определить права на каталог, создав список:

```
icacls c:\Directory
```

3.2 Сопоставить списки групп и прав.

По мне, так лучше воспользоваться powershell для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Запустив с правами администратора powershell и выполнить: `Get-Process -Name "processname" -IncludeUserName` можно узнать usera, под которым запущен процесс и исходя из этого определить права процесса.